# Rails 3 : How to call create action form Flex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, post

I have a rails app that records a video from the webcam. After the video file is saved on the flex server, I need to create a record on the database calling the create action on my rails app  from Flex.
How can I achieve this? I need a url with params to be called.  I think the 
authenticity_token is necessary to post data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do POST request with ActionScript and Flex framework to your serverside action. It can be a pretty default resourse with **create** action.

To pass authenticity token you have 2 options: 1) external interface via JS function, 2) flashvars.

Everything else it depends on requirements. If you can explain details, I can help you, because we are working on rails+flex application more than 3 years